# Struggles with has_many and belongs_to association when relationships are 2-3 deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I'm pretty new to Rails and setting up associations, so I suspect I'm missing something pretty obvious.  I'm trying to set up an app where one model has two models that it has_many of.  The second model belongs_to the first and has_many of the third.  And the third can either belong to the first or the second model.

Specifically, I have a wall model that holds pictures and collages.  The wall can hold either pictures or collages or neither.  Collages can hold pictures.

```
class Wall < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :collages
has_many :pictures
end  

class Collage < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :wall
has_many :pictures
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base  
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :wall
belongs_to :collage
end
```

The error I'm getting is telling me:

undefined method `picture?' for #Wall

Is there something I'm doing wrong with the associations I'm creating?

Comment: Should be `Class Picture` with big `P`

Comment: Thanks for the correction - was a typo, not the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_many association` on any model gives plural form of that method

Therefore Wall class has method `#pictures` available by this line:

If you want `#picture` method to be available you should use association as `belongs_to`

We can debug more into the exact problem if you tell where actually you are getting this error and what is your feature to implement.

Also name for Picture class should be with **capital P**

Answer (score 0):

`@cvibha`'s answer should help you with the associations

However, there's another problem you may need to consider. You're calling this method:

```
undefined method `picture?' for #Wall
```

Rails associations basically create a record as per how you define the association (`has_many :pictures` creates `@wall.pictures`). However, you're calling `picture?`

--

If you've got a custom method called `picture?`, this should work (albeit without the association working - as described in the other answer). The problem you have is I don't think you've defined `picture?`

I would do this:

```
#app/models/wall.rb
Class Wall < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    def picture?
        #your code
    end
end
```

Alternatively, if you're looking to validate the existence of a picture, you may wish to use in your view:

```
@wall.pictures.any?
@wall.pictures.first.present?
```